# Correct way to redirect a user after registration

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm wondering how to redirect my users after a registration in the "best" way.

I already know that there are at least 3 options.

- Use the php-function header()
- Use HTML - "meta" tag
- Use Javascript (And display the link for those without)

My users fill a form on a "create.php" site, send it via POST to the create.php file, which creates an entry in my database if the information is okay. If everything went okay, I want my users to be redirected to a "edit-account.php" site next.

Which would be the best way to do so?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always best to use a HTTP header.

Javascript may be turned off.
Meta-tags are not meant to be used for this. They *can* do it, but they're not meant to.

Stick to HTTP headers (using PHP's header function)

Answer (score 2):

Sending a redirect header with `header()` is the way to go here. It'll be *much* faster and is guaranteed to work.

The speed difference comes from the fact that the browser will act on a redirect header immediately whereas a meta tag or javascript will require a new page to be downloaded, parsed and executed.

@Tularis' points are also valid; JavaScript isn't 100% reliable; meta tags aren't meant for redirects. FYI: meta tags are usually for refreshing a page's content (and there are much better ways of doing this these days).

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is definitely php header function. Since HTML and javascript are client-side and php is server side, you can use php to control output with highest security.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the header function

```
header("location: edit-account.php");
```

Javascript can be turned off in browsers.